# Converting for loops to while loops

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having problems converting this *for* loop into a *while loop*. I am using python 3.6. It is supposed to print out something that looks like this when it has a constant of 3.

```
        |../\..../\..|
        |./\/\../\/\.|
        |/\/\/\/\/\/\|
```

But my problem is that I can't quite figure out how to convert the *for* loops into *while* loops.

```
    def triangle(constant):   
        for a in range (1, constant+1):
            print ("|", end='')
            for b in range (1,(constant-a+1)):
                print (".",end= '')
            for c in range (1, a+1):
                print ("/\\", end= '')
            for d in range (1, (constant-a+1)):
                print ("..", end= '')
            for e in range (1, a+1):
                print ("/\\", end= '')
            for f in range (1,constant-a+1):
                print (".", end='')
            print ("|")
```

The main problem I am having is that nesting *while* loops constantly leaves me with either a constantly looping program or a program that doesn't loop enough as it ends too early.

```
a = 1
while (a < constant+1):
    print ("|", end='')
    while (a < constant-a+1):
        print (".",end= '')
        print ("/\\", end= '')
        print ("..", end= '')
        print ("/\\", end= '')
        print (".", end='')
        a += 1
    print ("|")
    a += 1
```

This is my first attempt and I was wondering if I need to declare another variable to use to end the original *while* loop or if there is a way to still use *a*.

Comment: What is your question? What have you actually tried? How did it fail?

Comment: What is this thing supposed to do?

Answer (score 5):

```
a = 1
while a < constant+1:
    ...
    a += 1
```